# Get a random value for a property in xml using ViewAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using ViewAnimation to perform an animation. As I know, there are 2 way to achieve this:

1. Create it from Java

> ```
> AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
> fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
> square.startAnimation(fadeOut);
> ```

2. Load it from XML

> ```
> <alpha 
> android:duration="1000"
> android:fromAlpha="1"
> android:toAlpha="0" />
> ```

then

```
Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_out);
square.startAnimation(fadeOut);
```

The thing is that I want to set a random value between 0 and 0.5 for `toAlpha`. I would be easy if I use the first way. However, for the second way, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> for the second way, how can I do that?

I believe eventually you have to achieve second way via Java. The way I know is to create all possible files like `R.anim.fade_out_zero`, `R.anim.fade_out_one` for storing different toAlpha value then do random pick up in Java.

So it is better to choose first way rather than second way for setting random value.